# Difficulty in finding a counter example for a polynomial reduction

Tags: np-complete, polynomial-time-reductions, bipartite-graph, hamiltonian-circuit

I am doing some exercises on proving NP Complete problems and the first problem was directed bipartite graphs with a Hamiltonian cycle and the second one was undirected bipartite graphs with a Hamiltonian cycle.
For the first problem I managed to find a reduction from $DHC$ where for a given graph $G$, we duplicate each vertex $v$ to $v_L$ and $v_R$ and add the edge $(v_R,v_L)$, and for each edge $(u,v)$ we add the edge $(u_L,v_R)$.
 I tried doing  a similar reduction from $HC$ for the unidrected case, where for an edge $\{u,v\}$ we add both $\{u_L,v_R\}$ and $\{u_R,v_L\}$ but I got stuck trying to prove its correctness, and I understand that the problem is that since the edges are undirected this creates more paths, so a Hamiltonian cycle in the new graph won't necessarily come from a Hamiltonian cycle in the original graph. But I would really like to find a counter example so I can truly understand it and I'm having difficulty doing it. I would love some help.
 Thanks

Comment: Is there undirected edge $\{ u_L,u_R\}$ also?

Comment: Yes, for each $v\in V$ we add $\{v_R,v_L\}$ like in the first reduction.

Comment: How about this counterexample: original graph $G$ is composed of a single edge $(u,v)$. Then, the reduced graph has a hamiltonian cycle $(u_L,v_R,v_L,u_R,u_L)$. And, the original graph $G$ does not have a hamiltonian cycle. ?